# Unknown type in gdb

Tags: c

In this code:

```
...
size_t bytes_over=0;    //Number of bytes overthe region.
size_t byte_size=0; //Number of bytes overthe region.

if(isin_allocatedblock(mem, key_address,&bytes_over,&byte_size))
{
//** Seg Fault here
asprintf(err_msg_2nd,"%s:%d: %p is %Zu bytes inside a %Zu byte region allocated here\n",file, line, key_address, bytes_over,byte_size);
    }
...
}


bool isin_allocatedblock(struct memory *mem, char *key_address, size_t *bytes_over, size_t *byte_size) {
...
*bytes_over = (previous_alloc_ptr+prev_alloc_sz) - key_address; //Right side is 1901
*byte_size = get_metadata_recordsize(meta_rec); 
return true;
}
```

When print bytes_over in gdb right where it is assigned the new value I get

```
$17 = <unknown type>
```

When I print byte_size I get:

```
Function return type unknown.
```

I'm getting a seg fault on the asprint command so I'm trying to see the values of these two variables.  I "set complaints 5" in gdb and now I see this after running in gdb (the line number is the line where bytes_over has a value assigned to it):

```
During symbol reading, incomplete CFI data; unspecified registers (e.g., esi) at 0x8049acc.
isin_allocatedblock (mem=0x804cec8, key_address=0x804de64 "", bytes_over=
    0xbffff078, byte_size=0xbffff074) at memory.c:471
```

Comment: @nneonneo, I went back and made itt bytes_over and byte_size.  On the assignment line for bytes_over, "p *bytes_over" in gdb gives me <unknown type>.  Printing the right side gives me a valid number.

Comment: And you built with debugging, no optimization (`-O0 -g`)?

Comment: maybe you could try typecasting with size_t, `p (size_t *)bytes_over`

Comment: @nneonneo, I built with no optimization and -g I. In the function when I execute "p bytes_order" it gives me "(size_t *) 0xbffff078".  "p *bytes_over" and "p *((size_t *)bytes_over)" give me "<unknown type>".

Comment: I just added more information at the bottom.

Comment: I fixed my segmentation error, which had nothing to do with these two variables, but I still am getting the unknown type when I do a print in gdb.  Valgrind shows no errors.

Comment: Please make a [mcve], maybe a little less minimal and some more complete than what you have provided.